# Convert Json Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Json

```
    [
{"stars":1,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":2,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},
{"stars":2,"q1":2,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},
{"stars":3,"q1":1,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":1,"q5":1,"q6":1,"q7":0,"q8":1,"q9":1,"q10":0,"q11":1},
{"stars":4,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":1,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":1,"q11":0},
{"stars":5,"q1":0,"q2":3,"q3":3,"q4":2,"q5":2,"q6":0,"q7":2,"q8":2,"q9":2,"q10":2,"q11":2}
]
```

i want to get each row in diff variable like:

```
{"stars":1,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":2,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0}

data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

using javascript

i am trying this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "FeedBackGraph.aspx/getdata",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (Response) {
                debugger;
                var d = Response.d.toString();
                var final_string = d;

                var res = final_string.split(",").map(Number);
                console.log(final_string);
```

Comment: put your try before asking for help

Comment: You need a diff of each array element against some array not in the main object?

Answer (score 3):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the objects and return their values minus the first element. You can access these new arrays using their indexes.

```js
const arr = [{"stars":1,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":2,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},{"stars":2,"q1":2,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},{"stars":3,"q1":1,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":1,"q5":1,"q6":1,"q7":0,"q8":1,"q9":1,"q10":0,"q11":1},{"stars":4,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":1,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":1,"q11":0},{"stars":5,"q1":0,"q2":3,"q3":3,"q4":2,"q5":2,"q6":0,"q7":2,"q8":2,"q9":2,"q10":2,"q11":2}];

const out = arr.map(a => Object.values(a).slice(1));
console.log(JSON.stringify(out[0]));
```

And here's a version that will satisfy vlaz's concern with the issue of the keys possibly being in the wrong order:

```js
const arr = [{"stars":1,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":2,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},{"stars":2,"q1":2,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},{"stars":3,"q1":1,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":1,"q5":1,"q6":1,"q7":0,"q8":1,"q9":1,"q10":0,"q11":1},{"stars":4,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":1,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":1,"q11":0},{"stars":5,"q1":0,"q2":3,"q3":3,"q4":2,"q5":2,"q6":0,"q7":2,"q8":2,"q9":2,"q10":2,"q11":2}];

// get the keys from the first object
const keys = Object.keys(arr[0])

  // remove stars
  .filter(el => el !== 'stars')

  // sort by key q1 to q11
  .sort((a, b) => +a.match(/\d+/) > +b.match(/\d+/));

// map over the data again and build new arrays based on the
// ordered keys
const out = arr.map(({stars, ...el}) => {
  return keys.reduce((acc, c) => acc.concat(el[c]), [])
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(out[0]));
```

Comment: Object property order is not guaranteed, hence the order of the values is also not guaranteed.

Comment: ["The ordering of the properties is the same as that given by looping over the property values of the object manually."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) - so I'm going to assume the OP is ok with that.

Comment: You could still have `q6` showing up before `q1`. And OP may not even be aware of that. Too many people aren't.

Comment: Updated my answer @vlaz

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map()` to loop thru the array. Use `destructuring assignment` to remove the property you dont want to include (`stars`) and use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array.

```js
var arr = [{"stars":1,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":2,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},{"stars":2,"q1":2,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},{"stars":3,"q1":1,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":1,"q5":1,"q6":1,"q7":0,"q8":1,"q9":1,"q10":0,"q11":1},{"stars":4,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":1,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":1,"q11":0},{"stars":5,"q1":0,"q2":3,"q3":3,"q4":2,"q5":2,"q6":0,"q7":2,"q8":2,"q9":2,"q10":2,"q11":2}]

var result = arr.map(({stars,...r}) => Object.values(r))

console.log(result);
```

---

If you want the order of the array will be based on the key. You can create an `order` variable. Assign the order on the first loop of the `map()`. Use `Object.keys` to get all the keys. Use `sort()` to sort the keys.

Use another `map()` to loop thru the order variable and construct a new array to return.

```js
var arr = [{"stars":1,"q2":0,"q1":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":2,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},{"stars":2,"q1":2,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},{"stars":3,"q1":1,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":1,"q5":1,"q6":1,"q7":0,"q8":1,"q9":1,"q10":0,"q11":1},{"stars":4,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":1,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":1,"q11":0},{"stars":5,"q1":0,"q2":3,"q3":3,"q4":2,"q5":2,"q6":0,"q7":2,"q8":2,"q9":2,"q10":2,"q11":2}];

var order = null;
var result = arr.map(({stars,...r}) => {
  if (order === null) order = Object.keys(r).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true,sensitivity: 'base'}));
  return order.map(o => r[o]);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Object property order is not guaranteed, hence the order of the values is also not guaranteed.

Comment: I think everyone gets the message.

Comment: Do they? Three different high rep users came up with the same potentially wrong solution when this is one of the most common problems of newbies here on SO - people assuming that the property order of objects is "set".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `reduce` to build the array along with the function `Object.values` to extract the values for each object.

```js
let arr = [{"stars":1,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":2,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},{"stars":2,"q1":2,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},{"stars":3,"q1":1,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":1,"q5":1,"q6":1,"q7":0,"q8":1,"q9":1,"q10":0,"q11":1},{"stars":4,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":1,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":1,"q11":0},{"stars":5,"q1":0,"q2":3,"q3":3,"q4":2,"q5":2,"q6":0,"q7":2,"q8":2,"q9":2,"q10":2,"q11":2}],
    result = arr.reduce((a, c) => a.concat({data: Object.values(c).slice(1)}), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Object property order is not guaranteed, hence the order of the values is also not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = (row)=>{
  let {q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9,q10,q11}=row;
  return [q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9,q10,q11];
};

data(json[0]);
```

> Output **[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]**

- I am assuming that data has q1 to q11 only
- json is the response object

Answer (score 0):

Since [there is no guarantee of the property order in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order), you need to take precautions to make sure you get the correct result.

```js
var data = [
  {"stars":1,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":2,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},
  {"stars":2,"q1":2,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":0,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":0,"q11":0},
  {"stars":3,"q1":1,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":1,"q5":1,"q6":1,"q7":0,"q8":1,"q9":1,"q10":0,"q11":1},
  {"stars":4,"q1":0,"q2":0,"q3":0,"q4":0,"q5":0,"q6":0,"q7":1,"q8":0,"q9":0,"q10":1,"q11":0},
  {"stars":5,"q1":0,"q2":3,"q3":3,"q4":2,"q5":2,"q6":0,"q7":2,"q8":2,"q9":2,"q10":2,"q11":2}
]

var convertedObject = transformObject(data[0]);
console.log("transforming single object", convertedObject);

var convertedArray = data.map(transformObject);
console.log("transforming the entire array", convertedArray);


function convertKeyToNumeric(key) {
  var numericString = key.slice(1); //remove the first character 
  return Number(numericString);
}

function transformObject(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj) //get keys
    .filter(key => key !== "stars") //remove "stars"
    .sort((a, b) => convertKeyToNumeric(a) - convertKeyToNumeric(b)) //sort in ascending order
    .map(key => obj[key]) //get the values
}
```

- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) extracts the keys, so you can work with them.
- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) excludes the keys you don't want.
- [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) ensures the correct order of your properties, so they won't get processed in the wrong order, for example q8 --> q6 --> q10 --> q7 --> q9 --> q2 --> q1 --> q5 --> q3 --> q11 --> q4
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) then gives you the values.

The `convertKeyToNumeric` function is extracted for clarity. It can be re-written in a variety of ways, depending on the type of keys you get. This is strictly for ones that start with a single non-numeric character.

Comment: Thankx for answer but i am facing ajax response error in this method, like : var data = [Response from ajax] format is into "" braces like :"[{values}]" and when use slice for  split " from stating and ending of string this is remove [] from string not ""

Comment: @aparnarai this is because you are getting an *object* and turning it into a *string* when you call `Response.d.toString()`. You can just get `Response.d` in order to get it and process it as an object. If that's already a string, then `.toString()` is not needed at all but you should do `JSON.parse(Response.d)`.